# React Native negative flex (flex:-1)

Tags: react-native, flexbox

Actually flex (flex:1) occupy the free space of screen so if we set the Negative value so what should do.
like as flex:-1.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: So the question is if we set the flex:-1 , so what is the behaviour of screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually flex (flex:1) occupy the free space of screen so when we set the Negative value it will consider it flex:0.

so flex:-1 = flex:0